# Show text in the center of terminal screen in golang

Tags: terminal, go

I am playing with golang and want to create a simple terminal tool (on mac, but it should work on linux too). I need to display character "x" in the center of the terminal window. How can I detect width and height of terminal window and detect its changes?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A terminal package exists in the Go [crypto](https://code.google.com/p/go/source/browse/ssh/terminal/terminal.go?repo=crypto) repository:
In particular, check out the [GetSize](https://code.google.com/p/go/source/browse/ssh/terminal/util.go?repo=crypto#75) function

Answer (score 6):

A lightweight alternative to the usual ncurses option, is [termbox-go](https://github.com/nsf/termbox-go). This is a pure-go implementation of termbox.

It offers a simple API to get some 'graphical' stuff done in a terminal and is pretty decent as far as support for different terminal implementations goes.